# Want to simplify my std::vector push_back usage

Tags: c++, arrays, function, vector

I started working with std::vector in c++ and was wondering if there is a better way to write my code.

I tried to use push_back directly (example at the end of this question), but it looks like i cant use a class function inside the push_back function.

Here is the part in main i would like to optimize:

```
ShopTower st_temp;
    vector<ShopTower> shopTower;
    st_temp.set("Bow Tower", "images/tower/bowtowerBuy.png", 30, 30, 1);
    shopTower.push_back(st_temp);
    st_temp.set("Cannon Tower", "images/tower/cannontowerBuy.png", 30, 30, 2);
    shopTower.push_back(st_temp);
    ...
```

and my set function:

```
void set(string aName, string aAdr, int aH, int aW, int aNr){
            name = aName;
            adr = aAdr;
            size.set(aH,aW);
            setAtBottom(20+((aNr-1)*(aW+20)), 20);
        }
```

Just to make things clear, size.set is a simple height=ah width=aw function and setAtBottom is basically the same, but it sets the position counting from the bottom left corner.

If possible i would like to remove the st_temp variable and rewrite my code to something like this:

```
    shopTower.push_back(set("Bow Tower", "images/tower/bowtowerBuy.png", 30, 30, 1));
```

Comment: to make things clear you should include a [mcve] and explain what is the meaning of "doesn´t seem to work"

Comment: if you modify the constructor of ShopTower to take all the parameters you require. you can possibly do shopTower.push_back(ShopTower("Bow Tower", "images/tower/bowtowerBuy.png", 30, 30, 1));

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez please use the answer section for answers. Comments cannot be voted on and your solution is rather downvotable, OP is asking for optimizing, and you suggest them to create an unecessary instance and copy it, which is far from optimal

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 i hope my edited version is rule confirm - i actualy think my code examples are minimal reproducible examples, if needed i will ad the class, but i thought since it shall be minimal my set function explains the content of my class. I would need to post my class parents aswell since shoptower : myobject which contains the classes size(w,h) and pos(x,y).

If its still unconform i will try to edit my post again.

Comment: your example is still not reproducible in the sense that one can copy it and compile it, though at least now it is clear what you meant with "not working" and the example is enough to see why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you want `emplace_back`. You will need to have a constructor `ShopTower::ShopTower(string aName, string aAdr, int aH, int aW, int aNr)` if you don't already.

```
shopTower.emplace_back("Bow Tower", "images/tower/bowtowerBuy.png", 30, 30, 1);
shopTower.emplace_back("Cannon Tower", "images/tower/cannontowerBuy.png", 30, 30, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks - this is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

The straightforward way would be to create a constructor on the `ShopTower` class, and then `push_back` or `emplace_back` - **as already pointed out in the acctepted answer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57509445/2261538).**

***If for some reason that is out of the option*** (ie. you either cannot or will not add a suitable constructor) - then you can make a factory function that creates the object

```
ShopTower createShopTower(string aName, string aAdr, int aH, int aW, int aNr);
```

and using either:

```
shopTower.push_back(createShopTower("Bow Tower", "images/tower/bowtowerBuy.png", 30, 30, 1));
```

*or with `std::move` to avoid extra copies:*

```
shopTower.emplace_back(std::move(createShopTower("Bow Tower", "images/tower/bowtowerBuy.png", 30, 30, 1)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt would work if you returned (a reference to) your object from the `set()` function:

```
ShopTower& set(/* args */) {
    /* do the setting */
    return *this;
}
```

But there's really no¹ benefit from re-using a single object here, so just `emplace_back()` a new object each time instead.

---

¹ unless there's some contents of ShopTower you've not shared with us and need to be common across all of them (the question is lacking a good MCVE).